# Javascript in my SVG files do not run when wrapped in CDATA tags

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg, cdata

I have an SVG file in the form of the following:

```
<svg id="test" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 1435 1084">
<style type="text/css">
    svg{background:red}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    const x=1;
    const y=1;

    if (x===y){
        document.getElementById('test').append('<style type="text/css">svg{background:blue}</style>');
    }else{}
//]]></script>
</svg>
```

What I am trying to do is have a particular script *not run* when the SVG is embedded as an image object, but function normally when the SVG is embedded as an object or in an iFrame or when opened on its own in a browser. In particular, the code that needs to be blocked when embedded as an image includes a `<style>` tag.

The CDATA tag appears to be perfect for this job but it has not worked for me.

This has been a bit confusing. I have looked at SVGs that contain CDATA tags and run as expected, but for whatever reason when I do the exact same thing the JS never runs.

Also, bonus points if you can conceive of a concise way to create an SVG that can run different JS in the event it is; viewed standalone, inline, as object, as iframe and as image.

Any suggestions?

I've tried a number of things and have found my way to the CDATA tag as the most likely solution.

Edit: Including a code snippet. As I understand it, the SVG should have a blue background in this example but it renders red.

```html
<svg id="test" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 1435 1084">
<style type="text/css">
    svg{background:red}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    const x=1;
    const y=1;

    if (x===y){
        document.getElementById('test').append('<style type="text/css">svg{background:blue}</style>');
    }else{}
//]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: No scripts ever run in an image context.

Comment: Yes, but if I include a <style> tag in my javascript, the style is included in my image when it's embedded, which I am trying to find a workaround for (without setting the styles using javascript because that won't work for my case).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your script is throwing an error because jQuery isn't available in the environment where you're trying to run this.

If jQuery isn't available, this line will throw an error:

```js
$('svg').append('<style type="text/css">svg{background:blue}
```

If jQuery *is* available, your example works without modification:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 1435 1084">
<style type="text/css">
    svg{background:red}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    const x=1;
    const y=1;

    if (x===y){
        $('svg').append('<style type="text/css">svg{background:blue}</style>');
    }else{}
//]]></script>
</svg>
```

You don't need jQuery to do what you're trying to do. You could do the same thing with built-in browser APIs:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 1435 1084">
<style type="text/css">
    svg{background:red}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    const x=1;
    const y=1;

    if (x===y){
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerText = "svg{background:blue}";
        document.querySelector('svg').append(style);
    }else{}
//]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your solution appears to work in your Snippet but when I copy your exact code into a new SVG file and open it in a browser it renders red. Any clue why?

Comment: Your updated example has `id="test"` on the `<style>` tag, and you're trying to `append` a string with another style tag. I wouldn't expect the nested style tag to work.

Comment: I meant to add it to the svg tag, fixed--but the problem remains. Your solution appears correct in the snippet, but for whatever reason the exact code returns red when run standalone in the browser.

Comment: If you save your code snippet as an SVG and open it in a browser, do you also see that it returns as red?

Comment: It doesn't work as-is, possibly due to the particulars of using `innerText` in a style element--i'm not sure without digging into it. However, it _does_ work if I just do `document.querySelector('svg').style.background = 'blue'`. So you'd just need to figure out the details of appending style rules. The script is running.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the answer. It's an approach that could work if I didn't have a particular reason for needing a full <style> block to be appended.

Comment: @ray You are creating a `<style>` element for use as child of an `<svg>`. That needs a `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'style')` to work.

Comment: @ccprog ah! right! thank you. i don't do this sort of thing a lot, as you can probably tell.

Comment: ...and a second one: since `innerText` is a property of HTMLElement, and the created element does not inherit from that, use the `Node.textContent` API instead.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not execute scripts inside `img` elements. Here is no need to block code.

`append()` is available on DOM Level 3, but it works differently from what you expect (the jQuery method). String arguments will be appended as text nodes. They will not be parsed.

So you would need to create the element node and append it. This node has to be in the SVG namespace.

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1435 1084">
  <style type="text/css">
    svg{background:red;}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    const style = document.documentElement.appendChild(
      document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'style')
    );
    style.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css');
    style.append('svg{background:blue !important;}');
  //]]></script>
</svg>
```

However to just apply different styles I would add a class to the `svg` element.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1435 1084">
  <style type="text/css">
    svg{background:red;}
    svg.Active {background:blue;}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    document.documentElement.classList.add('Active');
  //]]></script>
</svg>
```